# How to detect when an element is in view in react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm a newbie working on a react native and got confused on how I can to be able to detect when an element say image/button is in viewport in react-native, If I can get a console.log function when user scrolls to that element it would be nice.

Below is my code,

```
<Block scroll  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>  
    
    <Block color={colors.card} flex={0}> 
        <Block marginLeft={20} row  alignSelf="center" 
          scroll
          horizontal 
          renderToHardwareTextureAndroid
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentOffset={{x: -sizes.padding, y: 0}}>
          <SectionedMultiSelect 
                      styles={{button:styles.selectButton,container: styles.container,itemText:styles.sectionedMultiSelectItemText}}    
                      
                      items={categories}
                      IconRenderer={MaterialIcons} 
                      uniqueKey="id"
                      subKey="children"
                      selectText="Select Service..."
                      showDropDowns={true}
                      readOnlyHeadings={true}
                      onSelectedItemsChange={onSelectedItemsChange}
                      onSelectedItemObjectsChange={onSelectedItemObjectsChange}
                      selectedItems={selectedItems}
                      single={true}
                    /> 
                      
        </Block>
        
        <Block card flex={0} marginTop={1} marginHorizontal="2%">
          <Block  // I want to be able to detect that this is in view port hence user has seen it
              card  
              row={isHorizontal}
              marginBottom={sizes.sm}
              width={CARD_WIDTH * 2  + sizes.sm}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
              <Image alignSelf="center" // I would really like to be able to detect that this Image is in view port hence user has seen it
                source={{uri:'http://192.168.56.1:8000/directAd/uploads/'+topPageAd.picture }}
                style={{
                  width: win.width/1,
                    height: 150,  
                    resizeMode: "contain",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    borderRadius: 20,
                }}
              />
              </TouchableOpacity>
               
            </Block>            
        </Block>            
        
        
    </Block>
</Block>
```

Comment: Try to use this API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API With it you can detect if your target component is in the viewport

Comment: Thanks, I checked but I couldn't figure out how to use the API in react native

Comment: You can try using the react-native-intersection-observer package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-intersection-observer